# JSOM get_url of image null or undefined

Tags: javascript, column, splistitem, image, jsom

I'm trying to get the url from an Image/Hyperlink field in a SP2013 List. My query works until I add in the request for Image data.

```
Unable to get property 'get_url' of undefined or null reference
```

I've followed other examples and still can't seem to fix the issue. My problem is that not all of the items in the list will have an image, so I want to try and validate this before I do anything with the information.

```
var siteUrl = '/blog/';

function retrieveListItems() {

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Posts');

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\' Ascending="False"/>' + 
    '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name =\'Modified\' Ascending="False"/></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></OrderBy></View>');
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(Id, Title,  Summary, Image)');

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

var listItemInfo = '';

var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

    if(oListItem.get_item("Image").get_url()){
    listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
        '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + 
        '\nSummary: ' + oListItem.get_item('Summary') +
        '\nImage url: '+ oListItem.get_item('Image').get_url();
       }
        else{
             listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
        '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + 
        '\nSummary: ' + oListItem.get_item('Summary');

        }
}

alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*sigh* ....

Turns out I should have removed the .get_url() from my if condition and it should have been:

```
if(oListItem.get_item("Image"))
```